# How to store table show hide columns in cookie

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sample code to show/hide columns for a table.  I would like to store the state( user selected columns) to a cookie, so that when the user comes next time or through a page refresh, the state is maintained.  I heard there is a jquery cookie plugin, but not sure how to use it.  Any examples which of the jquery cookie which I can use in the below code will be useful.

Below is the sample code

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script src="js.cookie.js"></script>

</head>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  if (typeof Cookies.get('col1') !== 'undefined') {
      $(".col1").hide(); // or show() depending what you want
    }
    if (typeof Cookies.get('col2') !== 'undefined') {
      $(".col2").hide(); // or show() depending what you want
    } 
    if (typeof Cookies.get('col3') !== 'undefined') {
      $(".col3").hide(); // or show() depending what you want
    }

    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
     /*   var index = $(this).attr('name').substr(3);
        index--;
        $('table tr').each(function() { 
            $('td:eq(' + index + ')',this).toggle();
            Cookies.set($(this).attr('name'), true);
        });
        $('th.' + $(this).attr('name')).toggle();
        Cookies.set($(this).attr('name'), true);
        */
         $('th.' + $(this).attr('name')).toggle();
        $('td.' + $(this).attr('name')).toggle();
        Cookies.set($(this).attr('name'), true);
    });
});
</script>
<body>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="col1">Header 1</th>
        <th class="col2">Header 2</th>
        <th class="col3">Header 3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tr><td class="col1">Column1</td><td class="col2">Column2</td><td class="col3">Column3</td></tr>
<tr><td class="col1">Column1</td><td class="col2">Column2</td><td class="col3">Column3</td></tr>
<tr><td class="col1">Column1</td><td class="col2">Column2</td><td class="col3">Column3</td></tr>
<tr><td class="col1">Column1</td><td class="col2">Column2</td><td class="col3">Column3</td></tr>
</table>

<form>
    <input type="checkbox" name="col1" checked="checked" /> Hide/Show Column 1 <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="col2" checked="checked" /> Hide/Show Column 2 <br />
    <input type="checkbox" name="col3" checked="checked" /> Hide/Show Column 3 <br />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) since a cookie gets sent to server for every single request ... every image, resource file etc. No need to add additional needless payload when server doesn't know anything about this cookie

You already have a matching classs on the header cells, if you add same class to all the other cells can use the `name` of input to match to those classes.

Store an array in localStorage and do something like:

```
// get data from storage and convert from string to array
var hiddenCols = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('hidden-cols') || '[]'),
  $checkBoxes = $('.col-check'),
  $rows = $('#myTable tr');
// loop over array and hide appropriate columns and check appropriate checkboxes
$.each(hiddenCols, function(i, col) {
  $checkBoxes.filter('[name=' + col + ']').prop('checked', true)
  $rows.find('.' + col).hide();
});  

$checkBoxes.change(function() {
  // toggle appropriate column class
  $('table .' + this.name).toggle(!this.checked);
  // create and store new array
  hiddenCols = $checkBoxes.filter(':checked').map(function() {
    return this.name;
  }).get();
  localStorage.setItem('hidden-cols', JSON.stringify(hiddenCols))
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/xzFFFBSCAjUw3Mywm0LO?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks , this worked.  How to avoid the flickering .. i think, when it loads, it display and then hide the columns.

Comment: Did you try it in a regular page instead of in demo? Could hide rows by default and do opposite on page load if that helps. Or use loading overlay...lots of visual workarounds can use

Answer (score 0):

You could use this Javascript API to make cookie access very easy: https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

Example (for your problem):

```
Cookies.set('col1', 'value');
Cookies.set('col2', 'value');
Cookies.set('col3', 'value');
```

And get them later:

```
if (typeof Cookies.get('col1') !== 'undefined') // col1 shown
if (typeof Cookies.get('col2') !== 'undefined') // col2 shown
if (typeof Cookies.get('col3') !== 'undefined') // col3 shown
```

EDIT: Integrated in your example. You would need to add the "colX" classes to all td elements of that column to make this work (also either hide or show them initially). There are other ways than this, but this is the fastest:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (typeof Cookies.get('col1') !== 'undefined') {
      $(".col1").hide(); // or show() depending what you want
    }
    if (typeof Cookies.get('col2') !== 'undefined') {
      $(".col2").hide(); // or show() depending what you want
    } 
    if (typeof Cookies.get('col3') !== 'undefined') {
      $(".col3").hide(); // or show() depending what you want
    }
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
        $('th.' + $(this).attr('name')).toggle();
        $('td.' + $(this).attr('name')).toggle();
        Cookies.set($(this).attr('name'), true);
    });
});
```

Comment: Appreciate your time.  New to Javascript, is there any way , can you help me how to integrate this to the example

Comment: Edited my answer. This might not be the best solution depending on your needs, but you should be able to go on from this.

Comment: Do I need to define Cookie ?

Comment: You need to include the plugin i linked in your html head `<script src="/path/to/js.cookie.js"></script>`

Comment: Tried that, but when I refresh, it's not working ..  Does this have to run on a server?  I just save this to my desktop and running from there ..  Let me edit the code..

Comment: Should work without a server. Check the contents of your Cookie in Developer console (F12 in Chrome).

Comment: Need to set checkbox state also on page load. Possibly not working based on original html in question did not have the classes on the data row cells. Beyond that check browser console for errors

Comment: Thanks everyone . Really helped.